# How to maintain the value of old arraylist after copied to a new arraylist and manipulation

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist as below:

```
ArrayList<List<Double>> myAr = new ArrayList<>();
```

I add the value to the array as below:

```
myAr.add(Arrays.asList((double)3,(double)4,(double)5,(double)6));
myAr.add(Arrays.asList((double)6, (double)8, (double)1, (double)4));
```

Then I assign to a new arraylist and copied myAr to temp as below:

```
ArrayList<List<Double>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
temp = (ArrayList<List<Double>>)myAr.clone();
```

I did some modification to an element as below:

```
temp.get(0).set(2, 9.0);
```

Then I display the output for both temp and myAr.

```
System.out.println(temp);
System.out.println(myAr);
```

Unfortunately, both displayed the same output. I want the myAr to be remain as it is. What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: You are creating a shallow copy when clonning, but you need a deep copy to copy inside lists values instead their references.

Comment: How to perform that? thank you

Comment: I would do `Arrays.asList(myAr.toArray())`

Comment: @FredericHenri that creates a different sort of ArrayList - a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList.ArrayList` instead of a `java.util.ArrayList`. e.g. the former doesn't support `add`, whereas the latter does. This is not necessarily wrong, but it could lead to confusing runtime bugs. I would use `new ArrayList<>(myAr)` so that it remains the same type.

Comment: FYI, you could just do this `myAr.add(Arrays.asList(3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0));` instead of casting all those integers to doubles.

Comment: It doesn't work Frederic Henri.

Comment: It does not matter @Craig as the last output still the same

Comment: Oh I know, its not an answer, its just an observation that (in my opinion) it's much easier to read than all the (double) casting you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement a deep copy, i.e. you actually need to duplicate the inner lists:

```
ArrayList<List<Double>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Double> list : myAr) {
  temp.add(Arrays.asList(list.toArray(new Double[0]));
}
```

otherwise the elements of `temp` and `myAr` point to the same underlying lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ArrayList you are clonig ie myAr contains(not primitive types) .To achieve this task you have to individually copy all the elements using a for loop.

Comment: False. He can use a copy constructor.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia ...and how are you planning to implement copy constructor without loops?

Comment: It's already implemented in all the collections. See my answer. What I meant by "false" is that he does not have to write the loop himself, easing readability.

Comment: My bad: you are correct: I didn't notice that OP's question posted a nested collection, and therefore the normal copyconstructor won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, it will work:

```
ArrayList<List<Double>> myAr = new ArrayList<>();

    myAr.add(Arrays.asList((double)3,(double)4,(double)5,(double)6));
    myAr.add(Arrays.asList((double)6, (double)8, (double)1, (double)4));

    ArrayList<List<Double>> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    //copy old list to new list (deep copy)
    for (List<Double> list : myAr)
    {
        temp.add(list);
    }

    //output original list  
    for (List<Double> list : myAr)
    {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Temp array");

    //editing value in new list
    temp.get(0).set(2, 11.0);

    //output new list
    for (List<Double> list : temp)
    {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Comment: Try to display the myAr at the end @Code_Bugs. It shows the new one

Answer (score -1):

.clone() creates a shallow copy (i.e. it creates a new collection and copies the pointers of the values in the collection, but does not copy the values).

If you want to achieve a deep copy, use a copy constructor:

```
temp = new ArrayList<>(myArr);
```

Comment: No problem @Diego Martinoia. Thank you for your kind help ;)